# Database column keeps reverting to null

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jhipster

hard facts:

```
<spring-boot.version>2.4.4</spring-boot.version>
<jhipster-dependencies.version>7.0.1</jhipster-dependencies.version>
<hibernate.version>5.4.29.Final</hibernate.version>
<liquibase.version>4.3.2</liquibase.version>
<liquibase-hibernate5.version>4.3.2</liquibase-hibernate5.version>
```

Database is postgresql 13.

My problem:
I am developing a platform where games can register to get access to other third party APIs. For this I have the class Game:

```
**
 * A Game.
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "game")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Game implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "api_key")
    private UUID apiKey;

    @Column(name = "api_secret")
    private UUID apiSecret;

    ....
```

The api_secret is to be kept secret, so it is only shown when the game is first created and otherwise always returned as null.
In irregular intervals, however, all api_secrets in my database are set to null, which then of course leads to access errors in the games.
Following relevant code snippets:

GameService:

```
/**
     * Save a game.
     *
     * @param game the entity to save.
     * @return the persisted entity.
     */
    public Game save(Game game) {
        log.debug("Request to save Game : {}", game);
        game = createApiCredentials(game);
        game.setUserExtra(userExtraService.findOne(getCurrentLoggedInUserId()).get());
        return gameRepository.save(game);
    }

    /**
     * Get all the games.
     *
     * @return the list of entities.
     */
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<Game> findAll() {
        log.debug("Request to get all Games");
        List<Game> returnList = gameRepository.findAll();
        for (Game game : returnList) {
            game.setApiSecret(null);
        }
        return returnList;
    }

    /**
     * Get one game by id.
     *
     * @param id the id of the entity.
     * @return the entity.
     */
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Optional<Game> findOne(Long id) {
        log.debug("Request to get Game : {}", id);
        Optional<Game> returnGame = gameRepository.findById(id);
        returnGame.get().setApiSecret(null);
        return returnGame;
    }

    /**
     * Get all the games associated to logged in user.
     *
     * @return the list of entities.
     */
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<Game> findAllByAuthenticatedUser() {
        log.debug("Request to get all Games");
        List<Game> returnList = gameRepository.findAllByUserExtra(userExtraService.findOne(getCurrentLoggedInUserId()).get());
        for (Game game : returnList) {
            game.setApiSecret(null);
        }
        return returnList;
    }

    /**
     * Generate new Api-Secret for game.
     *
     * @param id the id of the entity.
     * @return the entity.
     */
    public Game findOneAndGenerateNewApiSecret(Long id) {
        log.debug("Request to get Game : {}", id);
        Game returnGame = gameRepository.findById(id).get();
        returnGame.setApiSecret(UUID.randomUUID());
        return gameRepository.save(returnGame);
    }

    /**
     * Delete the game by id.
     *
     * @param id the id of the entity.
     */
    public void delete(Long id) {
        log.debug("Request to delete Game : {}", id);
        gameRepository.deleteById(id);
    }

    public boolean isGameRegistered(UUID apiKey, UUID apiSecret) {
        if (gameRepository.findByApiKeyAndApiSecret(apiKey, apiSecret) != null) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public Game createApiCredentials(Game game) {
        UUID apiKey = UUID.randomUUID();
        UUID apiSecret = UUID.randomUUID();

        game.setApiKey(apiKey);
        game.setApiSecret(apiSecret);

        return game;
    }
```

As you can see, there are many instances, where I set the apiSecret value to null, but in my opinion only when I return it to the user. And never do I call some save method.

GameRepository:

```
/**
 * Spring Data SQL repository for the Game entity.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@Repository
public interface GameRepository extends JpaRepository<Game, Long> {
    public Game findByApiKeyAndApiSecret(UUID apiKey, UUID apiSecret);

    public Game findByApiKey(UUID apiKey);

    public List<Game> findAllByUserExtra(UserExtra userExtra);
}
```

On the database, I have set up a trigger that records every change in the games table. Here I also see that a change is made by my programmatic user. That means it is not a manual intervention either, but really happens by the program.

Trigger logging:

```
public      | game       | dbadmin | 2021-08-29 11:02:13.084959+02 | U      | (5251,"GameName",,,,,gameKey,,00ucvnehiOJ85kZ3N5d5) | (5251,"GameName",,,,,gameKey,,,00ucvnehiOJ85kZ3N5d5)                                     | update game set api_key=$1, api_secret=$2, description=$4, name=$6 where id=$10
```

Possibly someone discovers my error or are there still tricks, how I can narrow the problem further?

Comment: When you set properties on a managed entity the state will automatically be persisted. So never do that unless you want it persisted. Instead of returning the entity, create a special class `GameView` or `GameDto` or whatever you like and map the fields from `Game` to it (either using a custom JPA query, or by using a mapper like MapStruct, or manually). But don't mess around with the entities and manipulate them. Another option is using a projection as supported by Spring Data JPA (which makes it pretty easy to do).,

Comment: Agreed with M. Deinum, see https://find-sec-bugs.github.io/bugs.htm#ENTITY_LEAK for more details

Comment: Instead of tampering with the entity better use `@JsonIgnore` to exclude this property from serialization.

Comment: Thank you very much M.Deinum for the hint and Guillaume for the link. Learned something again today. Funny enough I use DTOs for nearly all my other entities. I implemented the change.